# main method inside interface (java-8)

Tags: java, jvm, java-8, specifications

As java-8 allows static methods inside interface, I decided to check, will such simple compiled program successfully run:

```
public interface Test {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("I'm ok!");
    }
}
```

Surprisingly (for me) it runs perfectly.

What I am confusing about, is that in JVM specification terms `class` and `interface` have different semantics and usage. In this context I'm worry about is this behaviour is really according to JVMS or not? Because in fact [JVMS Ch. 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2). talks about `class`, not `class or interface`:

> The Java Virtual Machine starts up by creating an initial **class**, which
>   is specified in an implementation-dependent manner, using the
>   bootstrap class loader (§5.3.1). The Java Virtual Machine then links
>   the initial class, initializes it, and invokes the public class method
>   void main(String[]).

**UPD**:

I know, that interface itself is a class. But I'm talking about JVM, where often `class` and `interface` have different semantics. [For example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5)

> The run-time constant pool for a class or interface is constructed
>   when the class or interface is created (§5.3) by the Java Virtual
>   Machine.

Comment: An interface is a class.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen This is actually not about Java itselft specs, but about JVM specs. In JVM `class` and `interface` terms are strongly divided.

Comment: @Andremoniy maybe so in some cases, but you won't find references to a "bootstrap interface loader".

Comment: In the JVM they are all `.class` files. You can't create an instance of an abstract class or interface but there isn't as many differences as there used to be.

Comment: BTW You can't add static methods to an annotation. ;)

Comment: Nor can you add it to `package-info.java`

Comment: Most likely this was overlooked when revising the JLS.  An interface is just a special class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM spec is a bit lax in its wording here. If you refer to the referenced [section 5.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.1), it says:

> The following steps are used to load and thereby create the nonarray class or interface C denoted by N using the bootstrap class loader.

The point is that the same process is followed regardless of whether C is a class or interface.

The Java Language Specification is equally inconsistent in describing the virtual machine startup, at one point using "class" and at another using "class or interface".

In any event, having a `main` method as part of an interface should work perfectly well.